# How to escape in windows command shell?

Tags: windows, for-loop, escaping, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I've a file in `c:\Program Files` directory named `tmp.txt`

For each line in tmp.txt, I would like to execute a command.

I am trying to use command prompt `for` loop but it is not able to find the tmp.txt. Note that I've to run this command out of  `c:\Program Files` directory.

Here is how I am trying:

```
C:\>for /F %i in ("c:\Program Files\tmp.txt") do echo "%i"
```

the output is:

```
C:\>echo "c:\Program"
"c:\Program"
```

which means that `for` is considering `"c:\Program"` as parameter and passing it to `do`

If I put file in `c:\`, and run `for` loop as-

```
C:\>for /F %i in (c:\tmp.txt) do echo "%i"
```

it works just fine

So my question is- how do I pass full path to `for` loop so that `for` consider it as file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `usebackq` option to `for /f`:

```
for /f "usebackq" %i in (...)
```

This changes the semantics of the various quote characters, as the help states as well:

```
usebackq        - specifies that the new semantics are in force,
                  where a back quoted string is executed as a
                  command and a single quoted string is a
                  literal string command and allows the use of
                  double quotes to quote file names in
                  file-set.
```